# How spoofing applications work?

Tags: spoofing

What is the logic behind the spoofing applications? Is there a open-source spoofing application that i can read? And how would you code one? Let's assume we are coding the SpoofWhats, how would we code it? Is it just basic socket programming, we send some information about the target user to WhatsApp's server and they respond?

Comment: "Spoofing" is an incredibly broad term. But in my experience, it is usually applied to situations where a flaw in protocol design or its implementation can be used to circumvent authentication and thus tricking a peer into sending you information that you shouldn't have access to (such as tricking a client into sending you username & password because you convinced them you're stackoverflow.com). It all stands and falls by the knowledge of such vulnerabilities though.